# Relative frequency of pair of words in scala

Tags: scala

I am new to [`scala`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala) may be that's why getting these small doubts.
I have some tuples like `("The", "band"),("The", "show"),("done", "by"),("The", "band"),("done", "that")` is occurred `2` times and number of pairs starting with word "`The`" is `3`.

Therefore **relative frequency** for the pair (The, band) will be

- `2/3 = 0.66`

So what I ultimately want will look something like this `((The, band),0.66) ((The, show), 0.33) ((done, by), 0.5) ((done, that), 0.5)`.

---

What have I done so far is - my variable `items1` contains all the above pairs I mentioned so,

```
val result = items1.map(x=>(x->1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

This gives me something like this - `((The, band), 2) ((The, show), 1) ((done, by), 1) ((done, that), 1)`.

Now I also want the count of pairs starting with word "The" or "done" so that I can apply the divide operation. I was able to find the count of pairs starting with their first word in a separate variable but then I am not able to divide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your attempt of using `reduceByKey`, I assume the dataset you're handling is a Spark RDD.  Here's one approach using `groupByKey` and grouping of the result Map values to compute the percentage of individual word occurrences:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("The", "band"), ("The", "show"), ("done", "by"), ("The", "band"), ("done", "that")
))

rdd.groupByKey.mapValues{ arr =>
    arr.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size.toDouble / arr.size).toSeq
  }.
  flatMap{ case (k, vs) => vs.map(v => ((k, v._1), v._2)) }.
  collect
// res1: Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array(
//  ((The,band),0.66), ((The,show),0.33), ((done,that),0.5), ((done,by),0.5)
// )
```

In case it's an ordinary Scala collection, neither `reduceByKey` nor `groupByKey` will be a valid method.  A solution using `groupBy` will be similar, but slightly different due to its different method signature from RDD's `groupByKey`:

```
val list = List(
  ("The", "band"), ("The", "show"), ("done", "by"), ("The", "band"), ("done", "that")
)

list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues{ ls =>
    ls.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size.toDouble / ls.size)
  }.
  flatMap(_._2).toList
// res1: List[((String, String), Double)] = List(
//   ((done,by),0.5), ((done,that),0.5), ((The,band),0.66), ((The,show),0.33)
// )
```

Comment: Thanks Leo for your reply. I tried your first technique of using groupByKey. I wrote - val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(items1)) but after that its saying "value groupByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]]". Is this is not the correct way to use sc.parallelize ?

Comment: @Sam, from your error message, it looks like you have a nested `RDD[RDD[(String, String)]]`.  Your `items1` as mentioned in the question should already be a `RDD[(String, String)]`.  In other words, you can directly apply `groupByKey` to `items1` like: `items1.groupByKey.mapValues{...}.flatMap{...}`.

Answer (score 2):

this will work:

```
def calcFreqs(xs: List[(String, String)]): Seq[((String, String), Double)] = {
  val den = xs.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.length)   // Map(word1, counts)
  xs.groupBy(identity)                           
    .mapValues(_.length)                           // Map(pair, counts)
    .toSeq                                         // Seq(pair, counts)
    .map{ case ((word1, word2), num) => 
      ((word1, word2), num.toDouble / den(word1))} // Seq(pair, pair/word1 ratio) 
}
```

Comment: Interesting. could you describe the steps?

Comment: @J.Chomel added comments to do so

Answer (score 1):

**Given tuples List:**

```
val items =List(("The","band"),("The","show"),("done","by"),("The","band"),("done","that"))
```

**Using:**

```
 def  rFreq(items:List[(String,String)]) = {
 val a1 = items.groupBy(identity).map(x=>(x._1,x._2.size))
 val a2 = items.groupBy(_._1).map(x=>(x._1,x._2.size))
 a1.map(x=>(x._1,x._2*1.0/a2.get(x._1._1).get))
 }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> rFreq(items)
res99: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, String),Double] = Map((The,band) -> 0.6666666666666666, (The,show) -> 0.33333
33333333333, (done,by) -> 0.5, (done,that) -> 0.5)
```

Comment: This will be `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 1):

You first need to calculate the required numbers into a `Map` so that you can query them in `Constant` time. That way you can achieve the final result in `O(n)` time.

```
val items = List(("The","band"),("The","show"),("done","by"),("The","band"),("done","that"))
// items: List[(String, String)] = List((The,band), (The,show), (done,by), (The,band), (done,that))

val firstWordCountMap = items.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, Int])({case (accMap, (first, second)) =>
  accMap + (first -> (accMap.getOrElse(first, 0) + 1))
})
// firstWordCountMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(The -> 3, done -> 2)

val itemsCountMap = items.foldLeft(Map.empty[(String, String), Int])({case (accMap, item) =>
  accMap + (item -> (accMap.getOrElse(item, 0) + 1))
})
// itemsCountMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, String),Int] = Map((The,band) -> 2, (The,show) -> 1, (done,by) -> 1, (done,that) -> 1)

val itemsRatioList = itemsCountMap.map({ case ((first, second), count) =>
  ((first, second), count.toDouble / firstWordCountMap(first))
}).toList
// itemsRatio: List[((String, String), Double)] = List(((The,band),0.6666666666666666), ((The,show),0.3333333333333333), ((done,by),0.5), ((done,that),0.5))
```